# Chat schedule reminder email is off by an hour

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat

Three hours before the event starts, the system sent out emails saying:

> You registered for the following chat
>   events happening today on
>   chat.stackexchange.com:
>
> in 2 hours
>
> ...

The same thing is happening on the [schedule page](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/663/ask-ubuntu-classroom?tab=schedule). Though the times are correct (and it showing the time in my timezone is a real boon).

Comment: Do you know when *exactly* is was sent? For example, was it sent 2h55m before the event, perhaps?

Comment: was sent 2h58m before the session with the 2h reminder.  @Stefano and I are both registered for events in the AU Classroom Channel and that has events on it for which we are registered for (or running).

Comment: its actually correct - there is a meta.so question that covers how it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We now round the hours correctly (instead of picking just the non-fractional part), i.e. "in 2 hours and 58 minutes" translates to "3 hours".